# JQuery Checkbox Even

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox

I have the following fiddle1 http://jsfiddle.net/y6tCt/35/ . I need to build the `checkbox` list dynamically but for now I have hard coded two rows. When I click on one of the `checkbox`es it is not invoking the 'change' event.

I would be grateful if someone could take a look and let me know what I have done wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery live, as it works on dynamically created elements.

```
$(":checkbox").live('change', function() {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6tCt/42/

Comment: @Martin This does work and is a great solution, but hopefully you understand why your original did not work, if not then please look at some of the answers below which explain in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your dom is ready before the buildHTML(); has finished running.

Place the call to buildHTML(); as follows

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     buildHTML();
     $(":checkbox").change(function() {

        alert("here");

     });});
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the script its now working, http://jsfiddle.net/y6tCt/46/

here is the script I changed,

```
buildHTML();
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
            if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
         alert("Checked");
            } else {
                alert('Unchecked');
            }

        });});
```

Comment: May I suggest that `this.checked` instead of `$(this).is(':checked')` is more efficient, easier to type, and (in my opinion) easier to read...